# $ is not a function. (In '$(".accordion")', '$' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been building a little jQuery accordion this afternoon based off a codepen I found, it works fine unless I put it in Wordpress where i need it. I know it's probably something obvious but i've spent too many hours looking at it now and i feel like i'm going in circles.

Here's my wordpress code using some custom fields from ACF:

```
<aside class="accordion">
<div>
<span class="col-2 showitem"><?php the_field('show_date'); ?></span>
<span class="col-4 showitem"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
<span class="col-4 showitem"><?php the_field('show_city'); ?></span>
<span class="col-2 showitem">?php the_field('ticket_status'); ?></span>
</div>
<?php the_field('show_information'); ?>
</aside>
```

And my script on the page.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var headers = ["H2"];

$(".accordion").click(function(e) {
var target = e.target,
name = target.nodeName.toUpperCase();

if ($.inArray(name, headers) > -1) {
var subItem = $(target).next();

//slideUp all elements (except target) at current depth or greater
var depth = $(subItem).parents().length;
var allAtDepth = $(".accordion p, .accordion div").filter(function() {
if ($(this).parents().length >= depth && this !== subItem.get(0)) {
return true;
}
});

$(allAtDepth).slideUp("fast");

//slideToggle target content
subItem.slideToggle("fast", function() {});
}
});
</script>
```

I should also mention I am using this [Ajax Load More extension](https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/) on the site and when i remove anything to do with that from the page and just keep things simple, it works. so i'm 99% sure it has to do with the interactivity of both things. But jQuery is not my bag so I'm hoping someone smarter than me know where i went wrong.

I also have the P as display:none; because otherwise it shows up all the time.

Thanks for looking at my question!

JD  :)

p.s, the original codepen is here http://codepen.io/rbobrowski/pen/likvA/

Update:
I tried changing all $ to jQuery, then jquery. I also tried both of @jai's suggestions with no luck. I also tried the solution @freedomn-m linked to as well as checking and testing methods from multiple links in the search results with no luck.

Comment: You need to load the default `jquery` within your code first.

Comment: have you included jquery..???

Comment: Try including the `jquery` plugin or use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Most probably, the 2nd solution should work i.e. using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: @Sanchit definitely but `$` can be used see the answer posted.

Comment: Yes jQuery is loading in the head @TintuCRaju

Comment: @Jai, Yes you are correct. That is also an available option.

Comment: See "$" not defined, check for wordpress - oh look... refer to the 100s of dups in SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery is not defined wordpress window load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689273/jquery-is-not-defined-wordpress-window-load)

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress `$` sign is not available, instead you could change it to `jQuery` or put the code in an *IIFE* and you need to put the event bindings in doc ready block:

```
(function($){ // get it with '$'
   $(function(){ // <---doc ready block
      // put all the code in here

   });
})(jQuery); // <---pass jQuery here
```

Actually you need to put your code inside doc ready block but use `jQuery` as a wrapper and use `$` in the args:

```
jQuery(function($){ // use jQuery and pass `$` for a reference to jQuery.
   // code here.
});
```

Comment: Just FYI it doesn't need to be in an IIFE as the `document.ready` handler takes a single param which is jQuery itself: `jQuery(function($) { ... });`, see the 'Aliasing the jQuery namespace' section http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Using this has the same result @Jai.
    jQuery(function($){
    var headers = ["H2"];
    etc, etc (ran out of characters)
    subItem.slideToggle("fast", function() {});
    }
    });
    });

Comment: @Jdizzle oh really, then you can use the upper one. which in most cases runs.

Comment: check if you have jQuery in your page: `jQuery.fn.jquery` run it in browser console and see if it returns the jQuery version.

Comment: No luck with the top one either @Jai. Running jQuery 1.11.3 apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You should either replace all `$` by `jQuery`

or

```
jQuery(function($){ 
     // do all code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accordion code was too convoluted for my purpose, I ended up stripping it way back and solved the jQuery issue with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
my code in here
});
```

Thanks everyone for trying to help, it's much appreciated.